# Directive working in one controller and not in another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to follow the [foodMe](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Fzq60IBaSf5mnsLWhig5nhZ9cJT85sresp0NqNIwh1I/pub) example on AngularJS. I am on step 21. Instead of creating a ng-model, I tried to do it a bit different, created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LGmmxXuVBB7484aKzKip?p=preview) here. My issue is it only works in Restaurants.html and not inside Menu.html. I can even see the value of {{restaurant.rating}} when I view the source , e.g.

```
<span stars rating="{{restaurant.rating}}" readonly="true"></span>
```

In the HTML view-source I can see rating="3".

Only a small change from my plunker vs my sandbox is in my sandbox I use the ['Restaurant'](https://github.com/IgorMinar/foodme/blob/10b9a2a3e33d622c504ccf8cf13707120822fa8e/app/js/controllers/MenuController.js) resource to get the individual restaurant data.

Any thoughts/ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the property `restaurants` is an array of objects and in the `Menu.html` you aren't accessing it the proper way. Change it to

```
Menu Rating: {{restaurants[0].rating}}
<br />
<span stars rating="{{restaurants[0].rating}}" readonly="true"></span>
```

and it'll work. The same doesn't happen in the `Restaurants.html` because you're iterating through the array by using a `ng-repeat`.

Check out [this fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/PsULR2Lx4HsUFvnHDHQT?p=preview) of your Plunker.

**Update** After talking with @parsh in the comments, I could better understand the problem with his code. The issue is that the directive doesn't get re-rendered when its scope changes. That can be fixed by using a watch:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    scope.$watch('rating', function() {
        scope.stars = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            scope.stars.push({'fm-selected': i < scope.rating});
        }  
    });
}
```

I updated the [Plunker script](http://plnkr.co/edit/PsULR2Lx4HsUFvnHDHQT?p=preview) with the changes above plus a button to simulate a scope change from outside the directive.

Comment: Hmm, actually the property should be "restaurant" and not "restaurants" - since there will be only 1 restaurant in the Menu page. Please look at this [github](https://github.com/IgorMinar/foodme/blob/10b9a2a3e33d622c504ccf8cf13707120822fa8e/app/js/controllers/MenuController.js) page which mirrors my sandbox. So Restaurants.html - list all restaurants, Menu.Html - the individual restaurant.

Comment: I've renamed as `restaurants` so it makes sense since the property is an array. :) If it represents only one object, then it shouldn't be a list. I'll update the plunker script to address that.

Comment: Ah, I got your point, sorry my bad. I checked the api is returning an object, 
`{
  "days": [
    1,
  ],
  "menuItems": [
    {
      "name": "Bockwurst WÃ¼rstchen",
      "price": 4.95
    }],
  "price": 3,
  "rating": 3,
  "id": "esthers"}`
and as I mentioned before, in Menu.html i can see {{restaurant.rating}} = 3, so the call/returned data is correct. only when the call gets inside the directive, I see scope.rating as "".

Comment: [Continuing from my earlier comment], interestingly, your solution did gave me an idea, so in MenuController.js I changed `$scope.restaurant = Restaurant.get({id: $routeParams.restaurantId}); `$scope.restaurant = the object;` and it started working, I can see the stars as per the rating attribute. So I feel there is some scoping issue going on here? Maybe some kind of timing issue? Angular is trying to render the data, before the api call is returned?

Comment: Oh, I see now what's going on. Here it is: your directive is rendering the stars in the `link` function, but that happens only one time (the moment the directive is initialized). Since the `get´ method of `Restaurant` only fills the `restaurant` property when the request returns, the directive remains unchanged. You need to create a `$watch` in order to monitor the `rating` property and re-render the stars every time that property changes. I'll updated my answer to illustrate that.

Comment: awesome! that did the trick. it makes sense now. thanks a lot. Still have to learn more on directives.

Comment: A side question, instead of using "$parent" in "$parent.restaurant.rating" in using [`ng-model`](https://github.com/IgorMinar/foodme/blob/10b9a2a3e33d622c504ccf8cf13707120822fa8e/app/views/menu.html), is there a better way/option. can't we just use `{{restaurant.rating}}` (I can create another q if you prefer)

Comment: Didn't get it. Perhaps you should create another question with more information.

Comment: I created another q [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282700/replacement-of-parent-in-angularjs)