# Replacement of $parent in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Referencing my earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258910/directive-working-in-one-controller-and-not-in-another/18259197), why is the code using $parent here 
`<fm-rating ng-model="$parent.restaurant.rating" readonly="true"></fm-rating>`. The full code is [here](https://github.com/IgorMinar/foodme/blob/master/app/views/menu.html).

I have been reading blogs which mention to avoid using $parent, hence my question. Is there a better way to write that code? Or is there no way, since the filters on the home page need to affect the results as seen in this screenshot of the [app](http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/11/angularjs-example-applications.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fm-rating` declares an isolated scope, as seen [here](https://github.com/IgorMinar/foodme/blob/master/app/js/directives/fmRating.js#L6), which means it does not use prototypical inheritance to get access to the parent properties.

This is useful when you want a scope in which you can use any names without worrying about overriding a parent property. The only way to "break out" of this isolation is to use `$parent`, a property on the isolated scope that refers to the parent of the scope!

For more information, search for "isolate" in the [documentation of directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: This post on how scopes work in Angular is also useful: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Hmm, I understand the scope: {}, but I am curious, is this the only way to do it, or is there a better way not using $parent?